# Roundcube does not take password for user at login

Tags: password, roundcube

I have roundcube and docker-mailserver in docker containers. I've managed to make change of password possible by roundcube password plugin. I created 'mailbox' table and added two columns: 'username' and 'password'. Now this is working, all users can change their passwords.

But still roundcube is logging in users by passwords from /config/postfix-accounts.cf, not from database.

How can I make roundcube take passwords from database (MySQL)?

Surely IMAP and POP3 also should take password from database, not from the given file.

Roundcube 1.5.2, docker-mailserver 10.4.0.

Comment: Have you read the relevant documentation? What have you attempted? Have you read relevant config files for clues?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, yes. Seems like roundcube is missing code for login taking password from database.

Comment: Currently what I am trying to do is to make roundcube auth users by passwords from database, not from file. Maybe dovecot configuration needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there was much work involved + much research:

1. you must have separate MySQL container and containers using it
2. docker-mailserver must use these lines instead of `image`:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

3. Dockerfile must be:

```
FROM docker.io/mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dovecot-mysql
```

4. as you can see it must be run with `docker-compose` with `--build` parameter
5. `dovecot-mysql` must be installed as it is for plugin for getting password from MySQL database (this plugin must be enabled for roundcube in config file - to change passwords in database from roundcube)
6. in `etc/dovecot/10-auth.conf` you need to comment
   `!include auth-passwdfile.inc` with `#`
7. in the same file uncomment `#!include auth-sql.conf.ext`
8. in file `10-ssl.conf` make line `ssl=yes`
9. this may be needed for `userdb` also
10. make in your container database a table `mailbox` with columns `username`, `password`
11. add at least one user with password `$1$...` - encrypted
12. `dovecot.cf` file must have `ssl=yes` and you may want to add `disable_plaintext_auth=yes`
13. have `/etc/dovecot` as volume (take the files from inside the container)
14. in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` have:

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=mail_mysql_cont dbname=db user=username password=root_passwd_for_db
password_query = \
  SELECT username AS user, password \
  FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u'
user_query = \
  SELECT '/tmp' AS home, 9999 AS uid, 9999 AS gid;
```

15. in `/etc/dovecot/auth-sql.conf.ext` have:

```
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
```

I will update the answer later as I will work on the problem further.

EDIT:

To make password changing possible in Roundcube you need to have MySQL database attached and table `mailbox` created with at least columns `username` and `password`.